# How do I swap audio output of the left and right speakers?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, speakers

I have two speakers stereo speakers but when I use the sound control panel applet to test my audio configuration I get sound in the right speaker when the user interface indicates the right speaker and vice versa. Is there a way to swap the audio output from left to right and right to left?

UPDATE: The reason for this question is that I've recently rearranged my workspace and because of physical constraints the left speaker has to go on the right side and vice versa. I could of course solve this problem with a hardware solution but I'd rather use a software solution if one is available.

Comment: I'm actually surprised there's no (easily found and implementable) software solution out there.

Comment: @ Ciaran - To allow this to work in software in on all PCs would either require swapping around the audio datastream in software (something that would have to be done/allowed by Windows and generally accessible via an API), or to have all hardware agree to a specification that allows you to swap streams.  I can guarantee you that the latter is not true (my soundcard has no swap option on my PC), and the former, AFAIK, isn't true either.  Thus, your'e left with applications and specific hardware that support the option.

Comment: @ Ciaran - other OSs / audio systems might allow you to do this on other platforms though.

Comment: @Ciaran - What's wrong with just switching the speakers, or just switching cables ? It's not like, where audio's concerned, there's a shortage of cables.

Comment: Never seen one, but in my head, creating a plug that just reversed the cables shouldn't be that hard? I mean you have male to female and mini-jack to <insert other plug> and back. How about an R+L to L+R plug?

Comment: It's too old for me to be able to add my own answer, but there is a software solution that's easier to implement now.  [Voicemeeter Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) is currently free.  [Reference](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/voicemeeter-banana-audio-management-for-1-and-2-pc-streaming-setups.397/) Set windows default output to Voicemeeter VAIO, this brings the sound into voicemeeter (it lands in the blue section in the reference link).  Set A1 output to your speakers/headphones (green section).  In the A1 section, click Mono a couple times and you'll get the swap

Comment: @ChrisRudd You should still be able to add an answer even if the question is old.

Comment: Ok, then my rep is probably still too low on Stack Exchange.  I usually use Stack Overflow, and I forget there's a rep minimum to post an answer

Comment: @ChrisRudd I didn't realize that this question was put into 'protected' status by a moderator. You need at least 10 reputation in Super User to answer this protected question.

Comment: Ok, I was able to add it as a separate answer now that my rep's higher.  Should I delete the comment above or leave it for posterity?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could get a cable that splits into two channels and one that merges them again. Then just swap the channels inbetween. For example [this](http://www.nextag.com/Cables-to-Go-Value-612565930/prices-html?nxtg=a8a60a24051f-58AD6094886E9379) kind and [this](http://www.nextag.com/Steren-Audio-Y-Adapter-55446946/prices-html?nxtg=a8a60a24051f-58AD6094886E9379) kind, if I read correctly... cables and audio isn't my thing :p Anyways, something along those lines should work maybe work?

Comment: +1 and you can normally pick those 3.5mm to AV cable splitters up on eBay and similar places for pennies.

Comment: Yeah. And even buying them new anywhere shouldn't be especially expensive.

Comment: +1 for a suitable hardware solution, although i'd preferred a software solution.

Comment: The links don't work anymore.

Answer (score 38):

There is a software solution called [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/)

- configure it to attach to your output device (Usually something like: "Speakers - VIA HD Audio" or "Speakers - Realtek HD Audio")
- create a new file in C:\Program Files\EqualizerAPO\config, for example swapchannels.txt
- Paste the following line into it as its only content: `Copy: L=R R=L`, save the file
- Open Equalizer APO's configuration editor, make sure that your device is the correct one in the dropdown menu on the top right
- If applicable, remove all pre-configured options by clicking the red "minus" icon
- Click the green "plus" icon to add a new configuration for your output device, then navigate to the "Include configuration file" option, select your swapchannels.txt file
- Save/Apply the configuration. Left and right channel are swapped.

Source of tutorial [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1114172/how-do-i-reverse-audio-channels-win-windows-7#post_25271218).

For my own case I ended up using headphones. Mostly left and right do not matter for Windows sounds or even not for music that runs in the background. However, for FPS games it matters a lot ;)

Comment: I would choose this as the best answer since i tried it and it works flawlessy. +1

Comment: Great solution, here is the file online so you don't have to create it yourself: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Ivanca/2588f6c34f42209e2325f25219c7fabc/raw/7d13bfe01e1d49d4e84735bb714b1ee68bd8870e/swapchannels.txt

Comment: This app is also great for changing EQ to compensate for cheap speakers

Comment: I really don't know why this isn't selected as answer, being a pure software solution as requested by the author.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and also allowed me to reduce bass levels as a bonus. Awesome.

Comment: Still the best answer in 2020

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this. Simple, universal, and integrated in a great audio service/utility/equalizer.

Comment: Signed up just to upvote this. It worked without a hitch. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this same problem with a set of Logitech speakers whose cable wasn't long enough to be placed the right way round on my (long) desk - they seem to assume that the PC will always be underneath the monitor, or on the right hand side.

My sound chipset doesn't have any support for swapping channels, so I had to make an adapter plug/socket combo. Find someone who can use a soldering iron, and get a 3.5mm plug and socket, and several inches of stereo audio cable - should be done in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Some soundcard drivers actually have an option to swap the left and right channels in their Control Panel applet (eg. A Realtek adapter I used to have did).  I imagine this might have to do with the features of the specific sound chipset.  Other drivers/chipsets don't.

Some games/applications have software methods to swap the left and right channels in their settings/configuration window/file (eg. Final Fantasy VII PC, Winamp).  Others don't.

The only guaranteed-possible way to swap is to physically swap the wires/speakers in hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Most media player software should be able to do it for you, so at least you can listen to music and watch movies properly — this should solve at least part of your problems.

Here is the solution in VLC player: *Audio > Audiochannels > Reverse Stereo*.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a software solution that's easier to implement. [Voicemeeter Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) (it's currently free)

- [Reference link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200611182707/https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/voicemeeter-banana-audio-management-for-1-and-2-pc-streaming-setups.397/)
- Set windows default output to Voicemeeter VAIO, this brings the sound into voicemeeter (it lands in the blue section in the reference link).
- In the Voicemeeter VAIO section of Banana make sure A1 is lit (this means it's sending the sound to A1 output, it's usually lit by default)
- Set A1 output to your speakers/headphones (green section in reference link)
- In the A1 section, click Mono a couple times and you'll get the swap icon

Answer (score 2):

As posted by Avatar further up [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) is quick and easy and a completely software based solution, no fiddling with wires or breaking out the soldering iron or digging around in all your applications / games hoping they have the option to swap channels (most do not).  One application, does it all, quick and easy to configure and you can forget about it afterwards.
Here is a [link](https://www.audiocheck.net/audiotests_stereo.php) to test left and right channels.
I would just like to clarify on Avatar's post, there are two applications, "Configurator.exe" to select the device you want to edit so it can install drivers.
Then "Editor.exe" to import the config file to swap speakers.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a simple 2.1 stereo speaker setup (just a L + R + subwoofer) with a 3.5mm jack that plugs into your computer, then you can find a 6ft headphone extension cable that simply extends the reach of any 3.5mm plug.

I used to use one with my TV to extend the reach of my headphones from the TV's 3.5mm headphone out.

I just used that same cable to extend the reach of my speaker setup that had the same constraints as yours — the right speaker has the plug but it would not reach my PC's jack. Hope this helps.