# How to reverse left right sound channels?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, audio, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I swap audio output of the left and right speakers?](https://superuser.com/questions/22514/how-do-i-swap-audio-output-of-the-left-and-right-speakers)

New computer came with realtek hd audio and headphone speakers are wrong on all times of headphones, left is right, right is left. Have Asus m4a88td-m motherboard. Have windows 7 ultimate. Haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: Maybe it's just me - but why does this matter?

Comment: @hotei - I don't know about you but I can *definitely* make out if the left channel sounds were coming on the right and vice-versa

Comment: Maybe watching a movie on PC I guess I could tell it.  I use in-ear earbuds and I would just swap em so it never occurred to me.

Comment: It does matter when you need it to get positional cues in a tridimensional space, like when you are a gamer or do advanced audio editing. I do and it's a pain to have the cord between me and the keyboard. I've thought about cordless headphones, but I'm yet to find one with good sound quality and no delay.

Answer (score 6):

Ignore what the headphones say and put them on backwards.

Comment: Even back in 2010 (and even long before that), many headphones and earphones were not symmetrical and wouldn't fit comfortably on the wrong ears. ¬_¬

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed your motherboard's audio drivers?

There isn't a way to do this within windows. Check your driver utility's settings.