# Swap Left-Right channel for USB headset

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones, usb-headset

I have a usb headset and I need to switch left and right channels. The usb headset (hp h8000) does not have a software (it has drivers but nothing I can set options for). Is there any way?

This is different from the other question because this is a usb headset, modifying the hardware is not possible.

Comment: why do you need to swap the channels?

Comment: Because the headset is constructed in such a way that it is far more comfortable when wearing eye glasses if you wear in reversed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I swap audio output of the left and right speakers?](https://superuser.com/questions/22514/how-do-i-swap-audio-output-of-the-left-and-right-speakers)

Answer (score 2):

see https://www.reddit.com/r/headphones/comments/44symk/how_to_swap_left_right_audio_channels_with/

> Equalizer APO. Put "Copy: L=R R=L" in your config file on a new line.

Link to software: https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

wow, this is amazing: here is the same config using the editor:

[image: Copy Channels visual config editor]