# Switching LR Audio Channels, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

A question was asked for almost exactly the same problem on Vista (astonishingly almost *8 years ago* to the day) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/22514/how-do-i-swap-audio-output-of-the-left-and-right-speakers), and I'm hoping an easy solution will have appeared in that time (and 3 operating systems later!)

Due to a recent desk rearrangement, my speakers are now on the wrong side (left playing right audio and vice versa) and spacial constraints mean that I can't switch them around. Is there any way to change which channels they use without installing additional software or buying hardware?

Comment: Couldn't find a solution, so I just cut open the cable and switched the wires.

Answer (score 1):

Found this, worked for me:
Try this work around, download Equalizer APO:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/f...

Proceed to install it then launch it
Choose your default device
Click the Add button
Click Basic filter
Click Copy between channels
Click the Plus button to copy channels

Click Add assignment
Click in the Channel list box then choose 'Left'
Click 'Right' in other list box
Click Add assignment again
Choose right and left

Click File > Save

Restart